# NgRx Data custom URL generator

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-ngrx-data

I'm new to NgRx. After preliminary research NgRx and particularly the NgRx Data package appear to be a good fit for an application I am working on. One caveat is our entities are backed by micro-services with unconventional routes.

Each entity has its own micro-service, and any operation is further isolated with a base record ID within the URL params.

```
[microServiceRoute]/[baseRecordId]/entityEndpoint
```

I have a lookup table for the routes, but the `baseRecordId` would be held in the store. The NgRx Data docs has a simple example outlining the replacement of the URLGenerator.

How can I specify my microService routes on a per Entity basis, while also having this generator read from the store? Can this be done easily or should I approach this from a custom service per entity perspective?

https://ngrx.io/guide/data/extension-points#replace-the-httpurlgenerator

Answer (score 4):

You are totally right, you need to implement your own `HttpUrlGenerator` class that serves desired endpoints and is provided in the module that imports `EntityDataModule.forRoot` like

```js
providers: [
  {
    provide: HttpUrlGenerator,
    useClass: MyApiHttpUrlGenerator,
  },
],
```

Currently there's a configuration key that changes prefix of API, but it doesn't allow to specify endpoints per entity: https://ngrx.io/guide/data/entity-dataservice#provide-a-custom-configuration

```js
const defaultDataServiceConfig: DefaultDataServiceConfig = {
  root: 'https://my-api-domain.com:8000/api/v1',
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [{
    provide: DefaultDataServiceConfig,
    useValue: defaultDataServiceConfig,
  }]
})
```